# How Threshold Signatures have the same Address / Public Key

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, evm

I am learning about threshold signatures and their use cases on EVM Blockchains.

I am trying to understand how they are able to always have the same address.

Is the following correct? It is my understanding of how it works

> A smart contract exists on chain. This smart contract is the address
> of the TSS wallet. The smart contract has a function that decides if
> signatures are valid. If this function is called with the requisite
> (threshold) signatures from parties, it approves use of the smart
> contract address for on chain meta transactions.
>
> TSS does not have a way to work off chain to produce an Externally
> Owned Address (EOA) even in a two party case. It depends on a third
> party smart contract to authorize use of an address.

Sorry if I'm way off, it's quite hard to understand the underlying tech of TSS. As I understand it, there is no known way to create an EOA without re-assembling a private key e.g. with MultiSig right? Or can TSS produce signatures from the same address based on signatures of two parties, such that the TSS signature always represents the same address / private key that is not known by any party? Any examples or documentation would be greatly welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on multiparty computing (MPC) which I believe threshold signatures (TSS) are part of. Thus, I do not know if there is a way to cryptographic natively to have a stable EOA for TSS. But I know some multiparty computing hardware companies do this by providing generic multisignature solutions across multiple different blockchains.

However you can have a simple threshold scheme with Ethereum by

- Deploying a smart contract that lists its owners in the on-chain storage
- The smart contract needs to have just one function to check if the incoming messages contains enough signatures from owners
- The address of such account is the deployed smart contract address

[Here is a tutorial of building such a smart contract wallet](https://www.codementor.io/@beber89/build-a-basic-multisig-vault-in-solidity-for-ethereum-1tisbmy6ze) by Mahmoud Fathy.